# Adapter detect clicked component android

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a listview combined with an adapter.
In my listview I have multiple elements that contains multiple elements.
How do I detect what was clicked in the listitem?
I did it with an onclicklistener on each button in my adapter but isn't there a better way to make everything unclickable except buttons or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 'isn't there a better way to make everything unclickable except buttons or something?' If you don't set an OnClickListener on any given element, then you shouldn't be reacting to clicks on each element.

Comment: You should check out my new library that makes writing adapters much easier.. including of course what you need - adding clickable buttons inside your items. http://amigold.github.io/FunDapter/